# Is there a Stack Exchange site where I can post this question?

Tags: support, specific-question, closed-questions

I asked a question as to where the source for the Java JDK was, and the question was closed by a bot and later deleted.

The question is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75630991/where-is-java-developer-kit-jdk11-source-code-for-openjdk-11-0-16-when-there?noredirect=1#comment133475434_75630991

A bot closed this question with the reason:

> Closed. This question is seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more. It does not meet [Stack Overflow guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). It is not currently accepting answers.

Is there a Stack Exchange site where I could post this question?

My belief is that bot made the choice to close this question and that IMO the bot got it wrong.

IMO, this question is not *seeking a recommendation*.  The question is seeking for a **single right answer**.  There are not opinions on where the source code is.  There is one place where it is located, and it is that single answer for which I'm asking the question.  So, IMO, this should be reopened and answered.

One of the comments actually answered the question, so that comment could be changed into an answer.

Also, since this is the first time this has happened.  If there is a better way or place for me to ask this question please share that with me so I can be better in the future.

### Screenshot of post

A comment asked me to include a screenshot of the post so I'm including that next.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Were you looking to include it as a part of your IDE? Does it *have* to be only OpenJDK?

Comment: I was trying to loop over all of the entries in a Jave Keystore (JKS) file without using the alias name for the entry.  And yes it had to be OpenJDK and match the version of Java that I was using so I could step through code (not decompiled code) in the IDE.

Comment: "seeking a single right answer" - given that you have identified more than one candidate that appears to work, and expect to be told that one of them is the "single right answer", that is asking other people to choose. That's exactly what we mean by "seeking a recommendation". But aside from that, the key point here is the *seeking* part, since what you seek is a *resource that already exists*. We aren't a search engine.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The question was not closed by a bot, it was closed by three other users of this site.

It was deleted by a bot but that's just there to clean up old unsalvageable questions.

We don't allow recommendations for off-site resources i.e. we're not trying to be a proxy for your favourite search engine here and there is no Stack Exchange site that would do that.

Comment: Fair enough.  Thank your for the quick and concise answer and resolution.

Answer (score 11):

I don't think that question needs to be asked and answered on a Question and Answer site [that is focusing on](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

> - a specific programming problem, or
> - a software algorithm, or
> - software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
> - a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development

Knowing the location of where to download something, even if Oracle/Microsoft is at the other end screwing things up every other month, doesn't fit any of the above criteria. Having found the src.zip doesn't solve your problem. Having found a suitable holiday destination isn't the same as going on holiday.

We do have a neat location to gather essential trivia and that is called the tag wiki: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/info and the Java one looks well maintained. Maybe it is worth suggesting an edit there.

Interestingly you have an answerable question buried in your research:

> I'm looking for the source to the keytool application to see how that tool loops over all of the certificates in a keystore.jks or truststore.jks file.

What would happen if you basically ask:

> I want to loop over all of the certificates in a keystore.jks or truststore.jks file the same way the keytool application from the lastest JDK does. How would I do that?

I somehow expect answers that will show you the code and I will upvote any answer that links to the source code of the keytool as supporting background info. And downvote any code only answer.

You've now solved two problems:

- you know how to loop over certificates
- (with some luck) you know where the source is

Comment: Excellent suggestion.  Thanks for helping me learn how to get what I want AND benefit the community. :-) Best wishes.